# How can I upload a file (image, video, document) with one upload using PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, video, file-upload

I need to upload an from a clients computer to the server running the code. It wouldn't be hard if those files were less than 2mb, but since the file may be a video as well, I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Basically the file would be copied to a folder on the server and registered into the database.

code is pretty simple so far, but here it is:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload: 
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>  

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
         $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
         echo $url = "content/".$name;
         move_uploaded_file($temp, $url);
    }
    ?>
```

I'm first time posting here, sorry if the formatting isn't correct..

Comment: and the problem with the code you already have is??????? and " it does not work" is not an acceptable answer to this question

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials in Google for uploading PHP file. A lot of codes still missing in your code.

Comment: Perhaps what i asked wasn't precise enough. It wouldn't be hard if the files are less than 2mb. But I am expecting larger files, 500mb videos 4gb videos and that code doesn't handle it. I don't know what the best method is to upload large files to a server with php and tweaking the timeout and file size limit doesn't seem like a good idea so I came here. Perhaps there are better ways, and I'd like to hear of them if you happen to know them

Answer (score 0):

After tons of searching I figured it out and just want to share:

To upload a file to a server of any size larger than 2mb all you need to do is change the php.ini file to allow a larger max file size and a longer time out.